# Как сохранить диапазон в переменной для использования в цикле?

Tags: bash, for, range

Как сохранить диапазон для использования в циклах?

Есть программа:

```
handshake=("wink" "double blink" "close your eyes" "jump")
code=$1
result=()

if ((code >> 4)); then
  for i in {3..0..-1}; do
    ((1 & (code >> i))) && result+=("${handshake[$i]}")
  done
else
  for i in {0..3}; do
    ((1 & (code >> i))) && result+=("${handshake[$i]}")
  done
fi
```

Хотелось бы переписать примерно так:

```
range=((code >> 4)) ? {3..0..-1} : {0..3}

for i in $range; do
  ((1 & (code >> i))) && result+=("${handshake[$i]}")
done
```

Как это правильно сделать в bash?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/169511/13970074

Comment: Этот топик я видел, мне не понравились те решения, что там предлагались. Только что получил ответ на русском, и это решение превосходное. Оно не было найденно в английской версии сайта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Хотелось бы переписать примерно так:
>
> ```
> range=((code >> 4)) ? {3..0..-1} : {0..3}
> ```

[тернарный оператор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), конечно, присутствует в арсенале интерпретатора *bash*, но только при использовании [*арифметических вычислений*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html):

```
переменная=$(( арифметическое-условие ? значение-если-да : значение-если-нет ))
```

т.е., результат может быть только числом.

если же результатом должна быть строка или массив, то придётся применять какую-нибудь из форм условного оператора. например:

```
if логическое-условие; then
  переменная=значение-если-да
else
  переменная=значение-если-нет
if
```

или

```
логическое-условие && переменная=значение-если-да || переменная=значение-если-нет
```

для вашего примера логическое условие может быть записано, например, так:

```
[ $((code >> 4)) == 1 ]
```

---

по поводу присвоения переменной последовательности значений.

если вы хотите итерацию в виде перебора значений в строке:

> ```
> for i in $range
> ```

то и последовательность должна быть сохранен в виде строки. например:

```
переменная=$(echo {3..0..-1})
```

ещё можно сохранить последовательность в виде массива. например:

```
переменная=({3..0..-1})
```

тогда для итерации надо будет указывать именно массив:

```
for i in ${переменная[@]}
```

Comment: Ответ замечательный. Использовал для решения задачи: https://github.com/rabestro/exercism/blob/master/bash/secret-handshake/secret_handshake.sh